# Push updates to page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to try building a messaging app in Rails and I encountered a problem.

In a chat app, I need to push the messages to "USER2" as soon as "USER1" sends them (and in the opposite directon).
How can I implement some code to allow it to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/ - This is one of the obvious answers.

But if you're building a chat app, I'd suggest *not* using rails for the actual chat part.
Take a look at [node](http://nodejs.org). Node is *a lot* faster than rails and it is tuned specifically for server push. Using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) with node makes a chat app take about 10 minutes of work, with the resulting app being both scalable, *and* backward compatible with older browsers(by using the best available transport layer for your data, choosing of 5 options).
You can bridge Rails and Node in several different well-documented ways. One of those ways is by using a [Redis](http://redis.io) pub-sub layer. Or, if your app is really simple, just do the whole thing in Node.

TL;DR: Use Rails for authentication, views and what-have-you, use NodeJS for the actual chat part.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't/don't want to implement the client side routing logic yourself then you could use [pusherapp](http://www.pusherapp.com/) to handle that for you.